# Apache Wicket 6 browser tab context

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, wicket, wicket-6

For my apache wicket application I need some kind of browser tab context object similar to Application and Session just for single browser tabs.

The reason why I need this, is that all data viewed on a page in the application is related to a specific date in history. This date is currently stored in my Session object. If a user uses two (or more) browser tabs and changes the date in tab 1 and reloads the tab 2, tab 2 now uses the same date. But it should preserve its own date.

Of course I could implement a variable in the page itself containing the date, but there are many ways to navigate between pages and the date should always be preserved, except when a page is opened in a new tab. From then on, the new tab should store its own date.

Example:

Start at tab 1 on page 1 with date = d1: t1p1d1
User navigates to p2: t1p2d1
User changes date to d2: t1p2d2
User navigates to p3 using "Open in new tab": t2p2d2
User changes date on t2 to d3: t2p2d3
User navigates on t1 to p4: t1p4d2

The only solution I can currently imagine is passing the date in all links via PageParameters and storing it in the Page. When the date is changed, the variable has to be updated as well es every link on the page (that would be a complete page reload).

Are there any better ideas for doing this without bloating URLs? Something like a Page.get().getDate() or Tab.get().getDate() similar to Session.get().getDate()? Maybe some ThreadLocal or Javascript window.name magic or a servlet API feature...

Maybe someone has done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to use https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior.java to detect when a page instance is opened in two tabs/windows. This way you can save the Date as page property. If the AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior detects a second tab for the same page instance then just create a new instance of the same class: setResponsePage(getPage().getClass()). This way the new tab will show a new page instance with its own Date property.

Comment: Does this also work for different page instances? I use BookmarkablePageLinks with @MountPath annotated pages, so it is really rare that the same page instance is opened in a new tab.

Comment: No. This detects only when the very same page instance is opened more than once. If the page instances are different than you can store the date in the page hierarchy. It won't clash with the ones from the other pages.